# Difference between "ein großes Angebot an" and "ein großes Angebot von"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference in the meaning of the following two sentences?

> 1. Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot **an**  Museen.
> 2. Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot **von** Museen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot an Museen.
>
> Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot von Museen.

In this context of a selection of offers, both mean the same. The phrase with *an* sounds better.

But be careful, there's another context in which *Angebot an/von* means you are making/receiving an actual offer:

> Dieses Angebot an euch gilt nur heute.
>
> Dieses Angebot von euch gilt nur heute.

Here, only *an/von* determines who makes the offer. The speaker (an) or *euch* (von).

Comment: To me, "großes Angebot von Museen" is something some museums offer (a big offer from/by these museums), not the same as "großes Angebot an Museen", i.e. a big supply of museums.

Comment: Not if you prefix it with *Ägypten hat ein*.

Comment: To me, *Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot **von** Museen* sounds wrong. Sounds as if Egypt got a generous offer **from** some museums, not as if Egypt has a plentitude **of** museums. Only *Ägypten hat ein großes Angebot **an** Museen* sounds right to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, people use the phrase with *von* quite often.

Comment: People do a lot of unfortunate things. Doesn't mean they are right. Many times, people say "Platzangst" if they actually mean claustrophobia.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the accepted answer, I'll answer with my view on this.

To me, **von** sounds wrong, in this context.

It sounds as if some museums made a generous offer to the state of Egypt, which is probably not what is meant.

- *Ein großes Angebot **an** Museen* means something like *a plentitude of museums* or, more closely, *a large **selection** of museums*, while
- *ein großes Angebot **von** Museen* means something like *a generous **offer from** (some) museums*.

Answer (score 2):

According to *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* (various editions), both versions are correct and have the same meaning:

> (…) In der Bedeutung »angebotene Warenmenge« wird *Angebot* mit *von* oder *an* verbunden: *Das Angebot von / an Gemüse war gering.* (…)

However, newer editions mark the version with *an* as recommended.

A similar example with corresponding translation can be found in *Duden-Oxford - Großwörterbuch Englisch:*

> **das Angebot an** *od.* **von Gemüse ist immer saisonabhängig** the selection of vegetables available always depends on the season;

Answer (score 0):

Angebot an means offer to someone (if you are a seller)
Angebot von has the meaning for counter partner. ( if you are a buyer)

Comment: Hello, Mert, and welcome to GermanSE! While you are right in general, in OP’s example sentences, the answer by Janka is more likely to be correct.